# Issue with DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT at millisecond

Tags: java

I am using DateTimeFormatter but at end of milli seconds after 999 mill seconds its loosing the milliseconds field.Please let me know if this issue with java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            File file = new File("/users/test/filenamedate12.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            BufferedWriter bw= null;
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            for(int i=0;i<=1000000;i++){
            ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now();
            String  content =zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT);


                //String content = "This is the content to write into create file";


            bw.write(content);
             bw.newLine();



            }

            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
        }
```

output sample

```
2016-04-05T22:32:56.999Z
2016-04-05T22:32:56.999Z
2016-04-05T22:32:56.999Z
2016-04-05T22:32:56.999Z
2016-04-05T22:32:56.999Z
2016-04-05T22:32:56.999Z
2016-04-05T22:32:56.999Z
2016-04-05T22:32:56.999Z
2016-04-05T22:32:56.999Z
2016-04-05T22:32:56.999Z
2016-04-05T22:32:56.999Z
2016-04-05T22:32:56.999Z
2016-04-05T22:32:56.999Z
2016-04-05T22:32:56.999Z
2016-04-05T22:32:56.999Z
2016-04-05T22:32:56.999Z
2016-04-05T22:32:57Z
2016-04-05T22:32:57Z
2016-04-05T22:32:57Z
2016-04-05T22:32:57Z
2016-04-05T22:32:57Z
2016-04-05T22:32:57Z
2016-04-05T22:32:57Z
2016-04-05T22:32:57Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is intentional. From the javadoc of `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`:

> The nano-of-second outputs zero, three, six or nine digits digits as necessary.

In other words, redundant `0`s after the `.` are being removed for brevity.

The source code shows:

```
ISO_INSTANT = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .appendInstant()
                .toFormatter(ResolverStyle.STRICT, null);
```

The `appendInstant` method is responsible for this behaviour. The docs for that method mention it as well.